# Problems to install NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I want to install NestJS with the `npm i -g @nestjs/cli` command.

> npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli npm ERR! dest
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/.cli-seuz8ewr npm ERR! errno -39
> npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename
> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli' ->
> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/.cli-seuz8ewr'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /root/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T21_30_24_672Z-debug-0.log

I tried to remove the "node_modules" part and renaming the `../cli` to `/.cli-seuz8ewr`. After that, it gets killed with:

> Killed####⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠴ reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/node_modules/fseven

What could be the problem?